# Can I start implementing Game Center in my iPhone app, without having created a new app in iTunes connect?

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect, game-center

This is a repost of [my question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4664/can-i-start-implementing-game-center-in-my-iphone-app-without-having-created-a-n) over on the gamedev.stackexchange but there seems to be more Game Center questions and answers here.

I'm in the process of developing a game for the iPhone and I want to add Game Center support to it. The problem, as I see it, is that I need to have named my app, created an icon and uploaded screenshots etc. before I can create a leaderboard and start implementation?

My game is unfinished and the iTunes Connect developer guide seems to indicate that certain information can't be edited once entered. Can I just create a dummy app with fake info and then create a new app when I have my game finished? Can anyone point me in the right direction on this one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a dummy app. But I think the only thing that you have to decide on now, if you want to work on the real app from the start, is the identifier and the name.

Answer (score 2):

If you're creating a dummy app file it would be best to use a random name, such as a 20 digit random word made up of integers and characters say. If you later decide to delete the test profile but want the name for another app it cannot be reused. That's the life-cycle of that name done.